# Data is not shown in angular grid after loading from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using angular 1.4 with requirejs. I need to display the data (loaded from server) in angular grid but I'm having problem in displaying in grid at startup. Data is loaded successfully and not visible in the grid, while when I click on any of it header column, the data is suddenly visible and then it works fine. 
Here is the code for loading/displaying the data.

Angular code:

```
var paginationOptions = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 25,
        sort: null
    };
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        useExternalSorting: false,
        columnDefs: [
            {name: 'expireDate'},
            {name: 'lastUpdateDate'},
            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'type'},
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
                if (sortColumns.length === 0) {
                    paginationOptions.sort = null;
                } else {
                    paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
                }
                getPage();
            });
            gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
                paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                getPage();
            });
        }
    };  
    var getPage = function () {
        require(['path/to/jsFile'], function(obj){
            obj.getFHVUsersData($scope.gridOptions , paginationOptions);
        });
    };
    getPage();
```

its working fine and the event `getFHVUsersData()` is being triggered correctly for requesting data from the server.
Here is code where I'm getting the response from server:

```
if (ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
    fhvgridOptions.totalItems = resp.data.length;
    var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
    fhvgridOptions.data = resp.data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
}
```

`paginationOptions` and `fhvgridOptions` are the global variables for arguments in the `getFHVUsersData($scope.gridOptions , paginationOptions)` respectively.

Comment: couldn't find in your code where you notify the UI that the model has asynchronosly changed.. try $scope.$apply() after you have recieved the data

Comment: Thanks @Fraction , I'm new to angular to I don't know much about it. let me try

Comment: won't have these problems if you use `$http` to retrieve data

Comment: but how can I access my $scope variable in a requirejs file which is outside the controller ?

Comment: Why do you even need to do that? Show how you are using require.js. Angular should be managing the requests and data internally within your app

Comment: You can see the code I pasted, in first portion, that is angular controller code where I'm calling method in a requirejs file, which handles the process further

Comment: just use `$http` . I see no reason to use require to get data

Comment: @Fraction $scope.$apply() solved my problem. Thanks. You can post it as answer and I'll accept it.